# Ничего не происходит при выполнении селекта

Tags: android, java, sql

Проблема состоит в том что я из курсора вызываю делаю селект для вывода информации из базы, но почему-то когда я пытаюсь проверить как он работает он ничего не делает. Выбираю из листвью параметр, жму, в функции передаю id и по идее должно вывести параметры из этого id, а оно ничего не делает.

Айдишники все в порядке, если удалять то удаляет, если изменять то меняет, а вот тут дилемма, выводить не хочет. Позицию передаю правильную так что все по идее работать должно.

```
public static void shareData(Context context, long id) {

    try {
        DatabaseOpenHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int countRows = -1;
        String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM "+ Coords.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + BaseColumns._ID + " = " + id);
        Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            countRows = cursor.getInt(0);
            if (LOGV) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Count in Coords table" + String.valueOf(countRows));
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                float lat = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Coords.CoordsColumns.LATITUDE));
                float lng =  cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Coords.CoordsColumns.LONGITUDE));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Coords.CoordsColumns.COMMENT));
                Log.v("","" + lat + "  " + lng + "  " + name);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        sqliteDB.close();
        dbhelper.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed open database. ", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to update Coords. ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dajver, Видать сильно помогло, если Вы меня так щедро наградили :-) Расскажите что в итоге то? Пропуск строчки, order, или и то и другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас первое поле в таблице что ли countRows? и как вы определяете что первая запись всегда содержит его?

и Вы кодом `cursor.moveToFirst()` и `while(cursor.moveToNext())` явно пропускаете первую строчку из запроса. Может в этом дело? Если у Вас структура зависит от порядка строчек то Вам явно надо добавить `order by` в запрос.